# JSW tokens serverside (laravel) and/or clientside (angular 2)?

Tags: angular, laravel-5, json-web-token

I found some good resources about JSW (JSON Web Tokens).
I am working with Angular 2 rc1 and Laravel 5 and found some good resources:

1. https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt
2. https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs
3. https://auth0.com/blog/2015/05/14/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/

Do I need the implementation of JSW on clientside (Angular 2) AND serverside (Laravel)? What if someone types the url in the addressbar in the browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 requests JWT (Json Web Tokens) on login; Laravel generates it and you save it on the client-side (Angular 2) using localStorage. Then on each API call that needs Authentication, you send the JWT and validate it using Laravel (Middlewares are useful). 
Hope it helps
Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you for responding, so I guess I need the Middleware I found for Laravel, and the JWT service for angular. And implement it like you've explained right? What I can't get my head around is: is JWT only meant for server requests? Or does it mean I can use it for JUST / BOTH angular authentication too?

Comment: Jwt is a unique token generated for each user (with a secret key that you set on the server). Since angular 2 is a client-side framework and can't read Laravel's cookies; To make sure the user is authenticated, you generate a JWT on server side and save it in the database an on the client-side using localstorage (localstorage is like cookies). And when the user makes a request that needs authentication, you just compare the client-side one with the server side one; To make sure "this user" is really "this user".